# mysql foreign key mistake

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need help about this issue. There is a problem but I could not find it

**error message is**

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db_kiosk`.`tbl_oyunhareketi`, CONSTRAINT `OH_KioskID` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`OH_KioskID`) REFERENCES `tbl_kiosk` (`Kiosk_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION
>   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

**Here is my code c#**

```
string sql = "insert into db_kiosk.tbl_oyunhareketi (OH_OyuncuID,OH_KioskID,OH_Puan,OH_Tarih,OH_ControlRow) values ('"+Convert.ToInt32(Label4.Text)+"','"+Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text)+"','" + Puan_txt.Text + "' , '" + Tarih_txt.Text + "',1)";

Label3.Text = Kiosk_Drop.SelectedValue;

Label4.Text = Oyuncu_Drop.SelectedValue;
```

`Kiosk_Drop` and `Oyuncu_Drop` are the dropdownlist in ASP.net and they are in the `selectedIndexChanged` function. When I display the labels the values are coming properly but problem is insertion. DB attributes also `integer` but I couldn't find the problem.

Comment: This query is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Oykun, Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) regarding SQL injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have foreign key constraint that prevents you from adding rows to the child table before you have relevant information in the parent table.

In this case you should first populate `tbl_kiosk` before adding a row to `tbl_oyunhareketi`. Rows are matched by columns `OH_KioskID` and `Kiosk_ID`.

Comment: tbl_kiosk already populated in the system, I created a query inside the Workbench of Mysql. It is taken the values from the tbl_kiosk but in the code section it is not working.

Comment: Can you show content of the `sql` variable after, so that it shows how `Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text)` and other variables are expanded.

Comment: Error message means that outcome of the `Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text)` doesn't exist as value in `Kiosk_ID` column of the `tbl_kiosk`.